# Make ellipsized a TextView which has LinkMovementMethod

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TexView` which needs to be placed in maxim 2 lines and has a linkable text in it.
If I set LinkMovementMethod  to the text view I get a scrollable `TextView` and the ellipsize is ignored.

Xml code:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"

            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"/>
```

This is my activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        SpannableStringBuilder captionSpan = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        captionSpan.append("a very long text here a very long text here a very long text here a very long text here a very long text here a very long text here a very long text here a very long text here");
        captionSpan.setSpan(new CustomClickableSpan(), 1, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        tv.setText(captionSpan);
        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }

}


public class CustomClickableSpan extends android.text.style.ClickableSpan {

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setColor(tp.linkColor);
        tp.setUnderlineText(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
    }

}
```

If I do not set the movement method everything is working fine.

Answer (score 21):

I found solution!
Instead **setMovementMethod()** use **OnTouchListener**.

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
SpannableString spanText = new SpannableString(text);

//here set your spans to spanText

textView.setOnTouchListener(new TouchTextView(spanText));
textView.setText(spanText);
```

I got this **onTouchEvent()** from **LinkMovementMethod** class.

```
static class TouchTextView implements View.OnTouchListener {
    Spannable spannable;

    public TouchTextView (Spannable spannable){
        this.spannable = spannable;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if(!(v instanceof TextView)){
            return false;
        }
        TextView textView  = (TextView) v;
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
                action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            x -= textView.getTotalPaddingLeft();
            y -= textView.getTotalPaddingTop();

            x += textView.getScrollX();
            y += textView.getScrollY();

            Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
            int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
            int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

            ClickableSpan[] link = spannable.getSpans(off, off, ClickableSpan.class);

            if (link.length != 0) {
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    link[0].onClick(textView);
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Selection.setSelection(spannable,
                            spannable.getSpanStart(link[0]),
                            spannable.getSpanEnd(link[0]));
                }

                return true;
            } else {
                Selection.removeSelection(spannable);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And sure **TextView** should have this attributes:

```
android:maxLines="2"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: I seriously don't know how to thank you enough for this!! Saved me!

Comment: I'm glad to help you)

Comment: OK - this just saved my day. Amazing Google hasn't fixed this obvious flaw yet...

Comment: I honestly dont understand how this magic works, but it does! It fixed obvious bug in TextView, where autolink or setMovementMethod does not work together with justification. Thanks million times!

Answer (score 0):

I needed something slightly more flexible than the great solution by @Airfreshener. Hopefully it helps someone else.

Should be able to drop and replace instances of `TextView` with `ClickableSpanTextView`. You may need to add additional constructors to `ClickableSpanTextView` depending on your needs.

```
public class ClickableSpanTextView extends TextView {

  static class SpannableClickListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private static SpannableClickListener defaultInstance;

    public static SpannableClickListener defaultInstance() {
      if (defaultInstance == null) {
        defaultInstance = new SpannableClickListener();
      }
      return defaultInstance;
    }

    private SpannableClickListener() {}

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
      if (!(view instanceof TextView)) {
        return false;
      }
      TextView textView = (TextView) view;

      CharSequence text = textView.getText();
      if (!(text instanceof Spannable)) {
        return false;
      }
      Spannable spannable = (Spannable) text;

      int action = event.getAction();
      if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        x -= textView.getTotalPaddingLeft();
        y -= textView.getTotalPaddingTop();

        x += textView.getScrollX();
        y += textView.getScrollY();

        android.text.Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
        int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
        int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

        ClickableSpan[] link = spannable.getSpans(off, off, ClickableSpan.class);

        if (link.length != 0) {
          if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            link[0].onClick(textView);
          } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Selection.setSelection(
                spannable, spannable.getSpanStart(link[0]), spannable.getSpanEnd(link[0]));
          }

          return true;
        } else {
          Selection.removeSelection(spannable);
        }
      }

      return false;
    }
  }

  static class CompositeOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    OnTouchListener[] listeners;

    public CompositeOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener... listeners) {
      this.listeners = listeners;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
      for (OnTouchListener listener : listeners) {
        // Apply each touch listener in order until one returns true
        if (listener.onTouch(view, event)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  }

  public ClickableSpanTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    super.setOnTouchListener(SpannableClickListener.defaultInstance());
  }

  @Override
  public void setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener listener) {
    super.setOnTouchListener(
        new CompositeOnTouchListener(SpannableClickListener.defaultInstance(), listener));
  }
}
```