# Android - Ellipsize not working for a link in TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, ellipsis

I'm a newbie to Android and I have looked at similar questions asked by others without a definite answer, since, I think, my problem is a bit different.

I'm using a TextView in my program in which there can be links, text, numbers etc. following is the TextView I'm using.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:linksClickable="false"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="7" />
```

Although this is working for normal texts, the ellipsize does not work whenever links are present in the TextView. I'm using "autoLink" in order to show the user that it is link but had set `android:linksClickable` to `false`. Right now, I've added the ellipsize from the code but I want to know whether I can do it from the XML file itself.

Thank you.

Comment: So that means, there's no workaround for this from the XML file?

Comment: there is a solution, programmatically, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35735409/3682535

Comment: Yeah. Right now also I'm getting the ellipsis programmatically, using a different way (less number of lines) than the link you gave. But I was thinking whether there is any way that I can do it much better. Thank you for your reply, btw.

Comment: nah, it was a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191174). I don't know if they solved it or not.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think they haven't. Thanks again for your comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make ellipsized a TextView which has LinkMovementMethod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245862/make-ellipsized-a-textview-which-has-linkmovementmethod)

Answer (score 0):

I face a similar problem. Tried to use

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:linksClickable="true"
android:maxLines="6"
```

for my TextView, and it failed to ellipsize once some link was pasted inside.
Perfect sollution worked for me was sollution from here: https://gist.github.com/shayousefi/5b4709f8b2024dea735f

Pasting it here in case of anything happening with gist in future

```java
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011 Micah Hainline
 * Copyright (C) 2012 Triposo
 * Copyright (C) 2013 Paul Imhoff
 * Copyright (C) 2014 Shahin Yousefi
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.Layout.Alignment;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.StaticLayout;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * A {@link android.widget.TextView} that ellipsizes more intelligently.
 * This class supports ellipsizing multiline text through setting {@code android:ellipsize}
 * and {@code android:maxLines}.
 */
public class EllipsizingTextView extends TextView {
    private static final CharSequence ELLIPSIS = "\u2026";
    private static final Pattern DEFAULT_END_PUNCTUATION
            = Pattern.compile("[\\.!?,;:\u2026]*$", Pattern.DOTALL);
    private final List<EllipsizeListener> mEllipsizeListeners = new ArrayList<>();
    private EllipsizeStrategy mEllipsizeStrategy;
    private boolean isEllipsized;
    private boolean isStale;
    private boolean programmaticChange;
    private CharSequence mFullText;
    private int mMaxLines;
    private float mLineSpacingMult = 1.0f;
    private float mLineAddVertPad = 0.0f;

    /**
     * The end punctuation which will be removed when appending {@link #ELLIPSIS}.
     */
    private Pattern mEndPunctPattern;

    public EllipsizingTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }


    public EllipsizingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.textViewStyle);
    }


    public EllipsizingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                new int[]{ android.R.attr.maxLines }, defStyle, 0);
        setMaxLines(a.getInt(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        a.recycle();
        setEndPunctuationPattern(DEFAULT_END_PUNCTUATION);
    }

    public void setEndPunctuationPattern(Pattern pattern) {
        mEndPunctPattern = pattern;
    }

    public void addEllipsizeListener(@NonNull EllipsizeListener listener) {
        mEllipsizeListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeEllipsizeListener(EllipsizeListener listener) {
        mEllipsizeListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public boolean isEllipsized() {
        return isEllipsized;
    }

    /**
     * @return The maximum number of lines displayed in this {@link android.widget.TextView}.
     */
    @SuppressLint("Override")
    public int getMaxLines() {
        return mMaxLines;
    }

    @Override
    public void setMaxLines(int maxLines) {
        super.setMaxLines(maxLines);
        mMaxLines = maxLines;
        isStale = true;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the last fully visible line is being ellipsized.
     *
     * @return {@code true} if the last fully visible line is being ellipsized;
     * otherwise, returns {@code false}.
     */
    public boolean ellipsizingLastFullyVisibleLine() {
        return mMaxLines == Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLineSpacing(float add, float mult) {
        mLineAddVertPad = add;
        mLineSpacingMult = mult;
        super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        if (!programmaticChange) {
            mFullText = text;
            isStale = true;
        }
        super.setText(text, type);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if (ellipsizingLastFullyVisibleLine()) isStale = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
        if (ellipsizingLastFullyVisibleLine()) isStale = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        if (isStale) resetText();
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the ellipsized text if appropriate.
     */
    private void resetText() {
        int maxLines = getMaxLines();
        CharSequence workingText = mFullText;
        boolean ellipsized = false;

        if (maxLines != -1) {
            if (mEllipsizeStrategy == null) setEllipsize(null);
            workingText = mEllipsizeStrategy.processText(mFullText);
            ellipsized = !mEllipsizeStrategy.isInLayout(mFullText);
        }

        if (!workingText.equals(getText())) {
            programmaticChange = true;
            try {
                setText(workingText);
            } finally {
                programmaticChange = false;
            }
        }

        isStale = false;
        if (ellipsized != isEllipsized) {
            isEllipsized = ellipsized;
            for (EllipsizeListener listener : mEllipsizeListeners) {
                listener.ellipsizeStateChanged(ellipsized);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Causes words in the text that are longer than the view is wide to be ellipsized
     * instead of broken in the middle. Use {@code null} to turn off ellipsizing.
     *
     * @param where part of text to ellipsize
     */
    @Override
    public void setEllipsize(TruncateAt where) {
        if (where == null) {
            mEllipsizeStrategy = new EllipsizeNoneStrategy();
            return;
        }

        switch (where) {
            case END:
                mEllipsizeStrategy = new EllipsizeEndStrategy();
                break;
            case START:
                mEllipsizeStrategy = new EllipsizeStartStrategy();
                break;
            case MIDDLE:
                mEllipsizeStrategy = new EllipsizeMiddleStrategy();
                break;
            case MARQUEE:
                super.setEllipsize(where);
                isStale = false;
            default:
                mEllipsizeStrategy = new EllipsizeNoneStrategy();
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A listener that notifies when the ellipsize state has changed.
     */
    public interface EllipsizeListener {
        void ellipsizeStateChanged(boolean ellipsized);
    }

    /**
     * A base class for an ellipsize strategy.
     */
    private abstract class EllipsizeStrategy {
        /**
         * Returns ellipsized text if the text does not fit inside of the layout;
         * otherwise, returns the full text.
         *
         * @param text text to process
         * @return Ellipsized text if the text does not fit inside of the layout;
         * otherwise, returns the full text.
         */
        public CharSequence processText(CharSequence text) {
            return !isInLayout(text) ? createEllipsizedText(text) : text;
        }

        /**
         * Determines if the text fits inside of the layout.
         *
         * @param text text to fit
         * @return {@code true} if the text fits inside of the layout;
         * otherwise, returns {@code false}.
         */
        public boolean isInLayout(CharSequence text) {
            Layout layout = createWorkingLayout(text);
            return layout.getLineCount() <= getLinesCount();
        }

        /**
         * Creates a working layout with the given text.
         *
         * @param workingText text to create layout with
         * @return {@link android.text.Layout} with the given text.
         */
        protected Layout createWorkingLayout(CharSequence workingText) {
            return new StaticLayout(workingText, getPaint(),
                    getMeasuredWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight(),
                    Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mLineSpacingMult,
                    mLineAddVertPad, false /* includepad */);
        }

        /**
         * Get how many lines of text we are allowed to display.
         */
        protected int getLinesCount() {
            if (ellipsizingLastFullyVisibleLine()) {
                int fullyVisibleLinesCount = getFullyVisibleLinesCount();
                return fullyVisibleLinesCount == -1 ? 1 : fullyVisibleLinesCount;
            } else {
                return mMaxLines;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Get how many lines of text we can display so their full height is visible.
         */
        protected int getFullyVisibleLinesCount() {
            Layout layout = createWorkingLayout("");
            int height = getHeight() - getCompoundPaddingTop() - getCompoundPaddingBottom();
            int lineHeight = layout.getLineBottom(0);
            return height / lineHeight;
        }

        /**
         * Creates ellipsized text from the given text.
         *
         * @param fullText text to ellipsize
         * @return Ellipsized text
         */
        protected abstract CharSequence createEllipsizedText(CharSequence fullText);
    }

    /**
     * An {@link EllipsizingTextView.EllipsizeStrategy} that
     * does not ellipsize text.
     */
    private class EllipsizeNoneStrategy extends EllipsizeStrategy {
        @Override
        protected CharSequence createEllipsizedText(CharSequence fullText) {
            return fullText;
        }
    }

    /**
     * An {@link EllipsizingTextView.EllipsizeStrategy} that
     * ellipsizes text at the end.
     */
    private class EllipsizeEndStrategy extends EllipsizeStrategy {
        @Override
        protected CharSequence createEllipsizedText(CharSequence fullText) {
            Layout layout = createWorkingLayout(fullText);
            int cutOffIndex = layout.getLineEnd(mMaxLines - 1);
            int textLength = fullText.length();
            int cutOffLength = textLength - cutOffIndex;
            if (cutOffLength < ELLIPSIS.length()) cutOffLength = ELLIPSIS.length();
            String workingText = TextUtils.substring(fullText, 0, textLength - cutOffLength).trim();
            String strippedText = stripEndPunctuation(workingText);

            while (!isInLayout(strippedText + ELLIPSIS)) {
                int lastSpace = workingText.lastIndexOf(' ');
                if (lastSpace == -1) break;
                workingText = workingText.substring(0, lastSpace).trim();
                strippedText = stripEndPunctuation(workingText);
            }

            workingText = strippedText + ELLIPSIS;
            SpannableStringBuilder dest = new SpannableStringBuilder(workingText);

            if (fullText instanceof Spanned) {
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) fullText, 0, workingText.length(), null, dest, 0);
            }
            return dest;
        }

        /**
         * Strips the end punctuation from a given text according to {@link #mEndPunctPattern}.
         *
         * @param workingText text to strip end punctuation from
         * @return Text without end punctuation.
         */
        public String stripEndPunctuation(CharSequence workingText) {
            return mEndPunctPattern.matcher(workingText).replaceFirst("");
        }
    }

    /**
     * An {@link EllipsizingTextView.EllipsizeStrategy} that
     * ellipsizes text at the start.
     */
    private class EllipsizeStartStrategy extends EllipsizeStrategy {
        @Override
        protected CharSequence createEllipsizedText(CharSequence fullText) {
            Layout layout = createWorkingLayout(fullText);
            int cutOffIndex = layout.getLineEnd(mMaxLines - 1);
            int textLength = fullText.length();
            int cutOffLength = textLength - cutOffIndex;
            if (cutOffLength < ELLIPSIS.length()) cutOffLength = ELLIPSIS.length();
            String workingText = TextUtils.substring(fullText, cutOffLength, textLength).trim();

            while (!isInLayout(ELLIPSIS + workingText)) {
                int firstSpace = workingText.indexOf(' ');
                if (firstSpace == -1) break;
                workingText = workingText.substring(firstSpace, workingText.length()).trim();
            }

            workingText = ELLIPSIS + workingText;
            SpannableStringBuilder dest = new SpannableStringBuilder(workingText);

            if (fullText instanceof Spanned) {
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) fullText, textLength - workingText.length(),
                        textLength, null, dest, 0);
            }
            return dest;
        }
    }

    /**
     * An {@link EllipsizingTextView.EllipsizeStrategy} that
     * ellipsizes text in the middle.
     */
    private class EllipsizeMiddleStrategy extends EllipsizeStrategy {
        @Override
        protected CharSequence createEllipsizedText(CharSequence fullText) {
            Layout layout = createWorkingLayout(fullText);
            int cutOffIndex = layout.getLineEnd(mMaxLines - 1);
            int textLength = fullText.length();
            int cutOffLength = textLength - cutOffIndex;
            if (cutOffLength < ELLIPSIS.length()) cutOffLength = ELLIPSIS.length();
            cutOffLength += cutOffIndex % 2;    // Make it even.
            String firstPart = TextUtils.substring(
                    fullText, 0, textLength / 2 - cutOffLength / 2).trim();
            String secondPart = TextUtils.substring(
                    fullText, textLength / 2 + cutOffLength / 2, textLength).trim();

            while (!isInLayout(firstPart + ELLIPSIS + secondPart)) {
                int lastSpaceFirstPart = firstPart.lastIndexOf(' ');
                int firstSpaceSecondPart = secondPart.indexOf(' ');
                if (lastSpaceFirstPart == -1 || firstSpaceSecondPart == -1) break;
                firstPart = firstPart.substring(0, lastSpaceFirstPart).trim();
                secondPart = secondPart.substring(firstSpaceSecondPart, secondPart.length()).trim();
            }

            SpannableStringBuilder firstDest = new SpannableStringBuilder(firstPart);
            SpannableStringBuilder secondDest = new SpannableStringBuilder(secondPart);

            if (fullText instanceof Spanned) {
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) fullText, 0, firstPart.length(),
                        null, firstDest, 0);
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) fullText, textLength - secondPart.length(),
                        textLength, null, secondDest, 0);
            }
            return TextUtils.concat(firstDest, ELLIPSIS, secondDest);
        }
    }
}
```

Optional thing (to probably prevent some ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in production) is to replace isInLayout method with

```java
public boolean isInLayout(CharSequence text) {
    return mMaxLines == Integer.MAX_VALUE || createWorkingLayout(text).getLineCount() <= getLinesCount();
}
```

Also worth mentioning, that you cannon rely on `tv.isEllipsized` all of the time (and make dynamic show more/show less). That's because `tv.layout` is often null so that we have false-negative `isEllipsized`. Sollution is to make runnable loop.
Do thing like this after setting you "description"

```kotlin
            //reason for if = we will enter infinite loop when inactive content is not visible
            if (description.isEmpty()) {
                resolveEllipsized()
            } else {
                //reason for runnable = there is no show more button, because tv.layout might be null
                inactiveContentTV.post(showMoreBehaviorResolver)
            }
```

Where you `showMoreBehaviorResolver` is

```kotlin
        showMoreBehaviorResolver = Runnable {
            if (tv.layout == null) { // wait while layout become available
                Log.d(TAG, "post to runnable for show more/less button based on layout nullability")
                tv.post(showMoreBehaviorResolver)
                return@Runnable
            }
            //decide what to do with show more/show less/ and ... at the end
            resolveEllipsized()
        }
```

and `resolveEllipsized()` is something like

```kotlin
    private fun resolveEllipsized() {
        with(contentSizeToggleTV) {
            if (tv.isEllipsized) {
                this.isVisible = true
                this.setSingleOnClickListener {
                    onDescriptionExpandToggled?.invoke(true)
                }
                tv.setSingleOnClickListener {
                    onDescriptionExpandToggled?.invoke(true)
                }
            } else {
                this.isVisible = false
                this.setOnClickListener(null)
                tv.setOnClickListener(null)
            }
        }
    }
```